# Change css on current URL

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change my div style on my current URL.

if I am on my home page.

```
div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{
width:790;
}
```

if I am on some other page except my home page so I want my class like this.

```
div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{
width:590;
}
```

I tried it but I don't get proper output.

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://easyapuestas.com/')
{
  // alert("hiiii");
document.write("<style>" +
"div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{" +
" width: 790px;" +
"}" +
"</style>");
}
if (window.location.href !== 'http://easyapuestas.com')
{
// alert(window.location.href);
   document.write("<style>" +
 "div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{" +
 " width: 590px;" +
 "}" +
 "</style>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   var width = window.location.href == 'http://easyapuestas.com/' ? '790px' : '590px';
   $('div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2').css('width', width);
});
```

Comment: Actually, what is the class name of the div you are trying to resize? Are you aware of the fact, that you can't use dots as part of the name?

Comment: currently in my CMS's css file they give this code.`div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2` as 590. so this same class I want to change as 790 for my home page

Comment: That selector finds divs that have all of those individual classes, so that's fine assuming the divs do in fact have all of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you give a class or id to the body element of your main page you should be able to do it in your stylesheet without JS:

```
<body class="home">
```

And then:

```
div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{
   width:590px;
}

body.home div.layout-column.column-main.with-column-1.with-column-2{
   width:790px;
}
```

This works because on pages where the body *doesn't* have class "home" only the first selector matches your div(s), but on pages where the body *does* have class "home" *both* selectors match your div(s) in which case the first is overridden by the second.

Comment: Oh right, OK. If you can I'd still recommend putting the classes in the common stylesheet, but then use jQuery to do `if(window.location.href == 'http://easyapuestas.com/') { $("body").addClass("home");}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to check the pages other than home page using this

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://easyapuestas.com/')
```

{

that is the fault, It is better to split this by "/" using split(url) function, It will return an array. Then u can check the number of element of that array, using that I think u can use this

```
var url=window.location.href == 'http://easyapuestas.com/';
var split_arr=url.split("/");
```

// now u can check the count of this array if it is greater than 3 it will not the home page

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I got my solution.

I manage it by php. I get my current URL by PHP and then apply CSS to that particular class and it's working perfect.